# How to work with protobuf schema messages in Python Apache pulsar pulsar-client package?

Tags: python, apache-pulsar, python-pulsar

Is there a way to publish message to an Apache Pulsar topic using Protobuf schema using pulsar-client package using python?

As per the documentation, it supports only Avro, String, Json and bytes. Any work around for this?
https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/ko/2.8.1/client-libraries-python/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That enhancement is not complete yet

https://github.com/apache/pulsar/issues/12949

It is there for Java

https://medium.com/streamnative/apache-pulsar-2-7-0-25c505658589